# How to specify conditions for count measure in SSAS MDX?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssas, mdx, msbi

I have a fact table which has column with both positive and negative values. Once I process the cube I can see the count measure automatically added which gives me the count of rows. How can I write a condition on this measure so it will not count the rows with negative values. Please help thanks

Comment: Can you not just create a named query in the DSV to exclude the negative values? Then add that as a measure group and simply count the rows.

Comment: @TheDumbRadish Can you please elaborate on how to achieve this?

Comment: Not really sure there is much to elaborate. Normally you import tables or views into the Data Source View (DSV) of your SSAS project. Either create a view to exclude the negative values and import that into your DSV, or create a named query in your DSV to do the same thing (Google this if you don't know how - it is very easy). Then create a measure group using the new object as you would for any Fact and create the same count measure. It will be a count of positive values only, because that is what is in your view or named query.